# Global variable called "undefined" inside of a function

Tags: javascript

Why, oh why, do I get "undefined" on the following Javascript code?

I have 2 functions. The first is called onmouseover, and it updates a global variable that is a reference to the DOM element that we just mouseovered. I want to highlight the DOM element while it is the current reference, so I change its backgroundColor and its border. However, once I mouseover the next DOM element, I will want to reset the backgroundColor and border to their original state (of the previous DOM element that we just left).

In the second function, called inside the first, I try to save some of the style info of this global reference. However, inside of this second function, when I try to use the variable, which is currentEditingReference, I'm told that the variable is "undefined".

I redid the code where the variable "currentEditingReference" is handed into the 2nd function as an argument, and given a different name inside of that function, but I still get the same error, which is "undefined". Here is the error as FireBug shows it to me:

```
currentEditingReference is undefined
backupStyleInfoObject.backgroundColor = currentEditingReference.style.backgroundColor; 
Line 313
```

I find this amazing. I'm not sure if I'm running into some odd feature of Javascript's scope rules, or if this is some kind of copy-by-reference problem.

In the 2nd function, storeTheOriginalCssAttributesOfThisDomElement, currentEditingReference seems to be treated as a local variable even though I define it at the top of the page, in the global space, as:

```
var currentEditingReference = null;
```

I should not get "undefined" on a variable that I have defined as null. Null and undefined are 2 different types in Javascript.

I have dozens of functions where I use currentEditingReference as a global variable, but for some reason, in this one function, I can not seem to use it as such. Why?

Formatting the code to show up on StackOverflow turned out to be a hassle, so I posted the code here:

http://www.krubner.com/stackoverflow.html

UPDATE:

Is it possible that FireFox errors are simply wrong? I am now getting "currentEditingReference is undefined" on the 4th line here, which should be impossible since currentEditingReference was defined just 3 lines before.

currentEditingReference = eventTargetRef;

currentEditingReference = addUniqueIdToAnElement(currentEditingReference);

var newObjectToStoreDataFromCurrentReference = new Object();

newObjectToStoreDataFromCurrentReference.style = currentEditingReference.style;

newObjectToStoreDataFromCurrentReference.id = currentEditingReference.id;

storeTheOriginalCssAttributesOfThisDomElement(newObjectToStoreDataFromCurrentReference);

UPDATE:

I figured out the problem: when you return a global from a function, you basically overwrite the global. Because others will probably suffer from this in the future, I wrote up an example here:

http://www.krubner.com/javascript_scope_example.html

Comment: that is a heck of a lot of rambling to describe some code that you still have yet to show us... post it here if you want people to look at it.

Comment: Nowhere in all that have you shown how you actually define currentEditingReference, which is the most critical part.

Comment: *"Formatting the code ... turned out to be a hassle..."* 1. Highlight 2. Click *"Code Sample"* button **`{ }`**

Comment: Marc B, just before the call to the 2nd function there is the line "currentEditingReference = eventTargetRef;"

Comment: In IE there is window.event -object, in FF it is window.Event, and window.event produces `undefined`

Comment: Teemu, FireFox hands the event to the function, so if I'm in FireFox I get the event that way. Most browsers work that way. If I don't get the event handed to the function, then I can assume I'm in IE. So at that point I used the syntax normal to IE, which is window.event. The code is reliable about getting me the event in all browsers. That is not the part of the code that is breaking.

Comment: No one has any further thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Surely making a property/method call on a JS null object would result in undefined since null is a predefined JS object type which obviously would not have your method/property backgroundColor?  I would have made this a comment but couldn't for some reason...

Comment: Mark B, currentEditingReference is defined at the top of the page:

Comment: var currentEditingReference = null;

Comment: just before the call to the 2nd function there is the line "currentEditingReference = eventTargetRef;"

Comment: `if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e) {
 var eventTargetRef = e.target;
 if (!eventTargetRef) eventTargetRef = e.srcElement;`

Fair enough as long as e.target or e.srcElement are guaranteed to have a backgroundColor property I see nothing wrong...

Comment: Beeblebrox, "e.target" is guaranteed to be a DOM element so it should have a style object inside of it. That part of the code seems to work well. The problem with the code is the way the global variable is considered "undefined" in the second function, even though we just used that global variable in the enclosing function.

Comment: Then unless there's a problem with addUniqueIdToAnElement I haven't got a scooby.

Comment: Beeblbrox, that is what I was wondering too. Does passing a global variable to a function and returning render it into a local variable for the rest of that function? Because that is what seems to be happening. I'm rewriting the code now to test that theory. If that turns out to be true, I will say Javascript's scope rules are extremely strange.

Comment: Beeblbrox, apparently this was true. The code works now, with addUniqueIdToAnElement() using the global variable but not returning it. I find this surprsing, but returning from the function changed the global variable into a local one for the rest of that function.